# Generate a range in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My table layout is:

```
`userid` INT unsigned NOT NULL,
`doors` INT unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
```

`doors` is a bitmask, which is used entirely by PHP and not by MySQL in any way other than selecting.

I'm interested in putting together some statistics, so I wanted to do something like this psuedocode:

```
for i between 0 and 24
    select count from table where doors&(1<<i)
```

I could easily do this in PHP, but it would require either selecting all the rows and manually parsing their masks, or 25 individual count queries. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this in just one select query, using a `group by` for instance.

**Note that this is for one-time use, not something that will go on the production side**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where an integers table comes in handy. You can create one as follows:

```
create table integers(i int unsigned not null);
insert into integers(i) values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
```

Then you can run your query as

```
SELECT ( tens.i * 10 + units.i ) AS ii 
FROM   integers AS units 
       CROSS JOIN integers AS tens 
       CROSS JOIN table 
WHERE  ( tens.i * 10 + units.i ) BETWEEN 0 AND 24 
       AND doors & ( ( tens.i * 10 + units.i ) << 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bitwise functions in MySQL:

```
select sum(case when doors & 1 << 0 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as bit1,
       sum(case when doors & 1 << 1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as bit2,
       . . . 
from t
```

If you don't want to type the statements 24 times, then I would create them in a spreadsheet.